# How to add TabBar to the AppBar when the user reaches some point of the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the CustomScrollView to show the Image in the AppBar, and when the user scroll down a bit then the appBar will contains only the title of the image that I displayed in an animated way and that's what I want.

```
CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        expandedHeight: 100.w,
        pinned: true,
        stretch: true,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          centerTitle: false,
            title: Text(category.categoryTitle),
            background: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
              child: Hero(
                tag: category.categoryId,
                child: Image.network(category.categoryImage,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    errorBuilder: (object, error, stacktrace) =>
                        const SizedBox()),
              ),
            )),
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
          [
            Container(
              height: 100.h,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

But what I want to implement now that I want to add a TabBar to the bottom of the appBar when the user reaches a point in the SliverList, to show the categories that are related to the image in the TabBar, How can I achieve this,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Refer SliverAppBar

Comment: Please add expected output video or image?

Comment: if sliverAppbar fails, try SliverPersistentHeader